# How to populate a column with random date in a table which falls between 2 dates from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables like patient_record and surgery_record. I want to populate the `surgery_Date` column in `surgery_record` table with a random date which falls between the `Beg_Date` and `End_Date` values in the `patient_record` table (`Beg_Date` and `End_Date` are the dates of patient admittance and discharge respectively. Currently I have the following query. Thanks in advance

**patient_record:**

```
Beg_Date = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 365), '01/01/2000')
End_Date = DATEADD(DAY, 85 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 11), Beg_Date)
```

**surgery_record:**

```
update Surgery_Record
set Surgery_Date =  DATEADD(DAY, 85 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 11), patient_record.Beg_Date)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "patient_record.Beg_Date" could not be bound.
```

I understand that I must have a relationship between these two tables to use the attributes commonly and I already have a foreign key constraint on a different attribute. If this is not enough please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update Surgery_Record
set Surgery_Date =  DATEADD(DAY, 85 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 11), patient_record.Beg_Date)
from patient_record
where patient_record.PatID=Surgery_Record.PatID
```